# Insert multiple values and sum php+mysql

Tags: mysql

I hope that somebody can help me.

I want to copy all the data from table A to table B and sum some of the values of table A and insert the result on table B with the rest of the information.

Here is my sentences:

```
INSERT INTO carga ( Item, REC_Rep, Invoices, Description, Qty, Skids, Boxes, Bins, Metal_Rack, Totes, Other, tqty, tskids, tboxes, tbins, tmetal, ttotes, tother) 
SELECT DISTINCT Item, REC_Rep, Invoices, Description, Qty, Skids, Boxes, Bins, Metal_Rack, Totes, Other, SUM(Qty) AS Qty, SUM(Skids) AS Skids, SUM(Boxes) AS Boxes, SUM(Bins) AS Bins, SUM(Metal_Rack) AS Metal, SUM(Totes) AS Totes, SUM(Other) AS Other 
FROM tmp_carga
```

If I run this sentences, I got only one register.

how can I get all the data or registers from Tabla A (tmp_carga), sum some values and Insert those values into Tabla B(carga) with the rest of the information?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You should look into using `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the aggregation function SUM, but you are not grouping on anything in your select query. This creates a "total sum" of everything. Find the unique key in your select (i.e. Item) and `group by` on this

Comment: thank you for the information, now I got all the records, but unfortunately I don't get the sum of the values. can you tell me if this sentences is correct: SELECT DISTINCT Item, REC_Rep, Invoices, Description, Qty, Skids, Boxes, Bins, Metal_Rack, Totes, Other, SUM(Qty) AS Qty, SUM(Skids) AS Skids, SUM(Boxes) AS Boxes, SUM(Bins) AS Bins, SUM(Metal_Rack) AS Metal, SUM(Totes) AS Totes, SUM(Other) AS Other FROM tmp_carga                   Thank you very much for your time